# How to set the priority for specific products in implicit als?

Tags: recommendation-engine

I have to update the recommendation system by setting certain products with highest priority. How can we achieve using implicit feedback data.

Comment: You should have a look at `Collaborative Filtering` for that.

Comment: kindly help out with the suggestions

Comment: Just search Collaborative Filtering or Collaborative Filtering with implicit feedback data and you'll find a lot of articles.

Comment: I have built the recommendation model using implicit feedback datasets, now i have to recommend for certain list of users and items with highest priority and rest with the minumum priority. How can we achieve this ? kindly suggest on this.